# Yellow is a bit stressing for the eye, change the highlight color of linked chat message

Tags: feature-request, design, chat

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16052270#16052270

[image]

I suggest a lighter shade with a bordered background.

Edit: I'll go with the color what the chat input box has: `#FBF2D9`, with a suitable black dashed thin border (if need be). However, the color change is a must.

> [image]

Comment: "Suggest a lighter shade with a bordered background." Yes, please do.

Comment: true! it lit fire to eyes :p

Comment: I took the liberty to add a mockup using your suggestion, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ShadowWizard For me it looks okay. But I'd rather say you go on a vote and invite other people to also sort of suggest something appropriate. More importantly we need to experience how does this look when the chat message is a single line...

Comment: A bit lazy, but here's a quick JS injection fix: `var newStyle = document.createElement('style'); newStyle.innerText = '.highlight { background-color: #FBF2D9!important;}'; document.body.appendChild(newStyle);`